# How to find a derivative of $f(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{xt^{-2}}dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, derivatives

Let $$f(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{xt^{-2}}dt$$
I want to find $$f'(x)$$

I tried to use taylor expansion:
$$e^{xt^{-2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^nt^{-2n}} {n!}$$
Indefinite integral gives,
$$\int e^{xt^{-2}}dt=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^nt^{-2n}} {n!}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int \frac {x^nt^{-2n}} {n!}dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^nt^{-2n+1}} {(-2n+1)n!}$$
Hence, $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{-3n+2}} {(-2n+1)n!}$$
Thus,$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-3n+2)x^{-3n+1}} {(-2n+1)n!}$$

And I am stuck here. Can you give me some tips to proceed from here? Indeed, I am not even sure what I've done so far is correct. Also, is there a better way to solve this problem (without using taylor expansion)? I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Note that for $x>0$, the integral blows up at the origin; furthermore, integrating negative integer powers of $t$ from $0$ to $x$ is also going to blow up. Though this is more an issue of convergence than finding series.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You just need the fundamental theorem of calculus (the so-called "second version"). It helps to rewrite the integral with the $u$-substitution $u=t/\sqrt x $.

Comment: Your substitution implies $x>0,$ but the given integral equals $\infty$ for all such $x.$

Comment: Well, in the $x<0$ case, we can take $u=t/\sqrt{|x|}$

Answer (score 1):

As Omnomnomnom answered, what you need is to apply  the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Applied to $$I=\int_0^{a(x)} f(x,t) \, dt$$ it leads to $$\frac {dI}{dx}=a'(x) f(x,a(x))+\int_0^{a(x)} f'_x(x,t) \, dt$$ Applied to your case $a(x)=x^2$, $f(x,t)=e^{x t^{-2}}$ this gives $$\frac {dI}{dx}=2 x e^{-\frac{1}{x^3}} - \int_0^{x^2}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{t^2}}}{t^2}\,dt=2 x e^{-\frac{1}{x^3}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }x^{3/2} \left(1-
   \text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right)\right)}{2 x^2}$$ $$\frac {dI}{dx}=2x e^{-\frac{1}{x^3}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,
   \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

using Leibniz integral rule,

$$f'(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{xt^{-2}}t^{-2}dt+e^{x (x^2)^{-2}}2x$$

The anti-derivative exists but it goes to infinite at 0.